# How to create a full-text index using properties of subclasses in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Let's say I have an abstract class `Animal`, and subclasses `Dog` and `Cat`.

My MongoDB table stores all animals, and uses a the `_t` type discriminator field in documents.

What I want to do is create a full-text index on 2 properties, one that exists only in `Dog` documents, and one that exists only in `Cat` documents. The JSON is straightfoward enough:

```
{ 
    "dog_only_field" : "text", 
    "cat_only_field" : "text"
}
```

But I'd like to do this with the official C# driver. I tried this:

```
var builder = Builders<Animal>.IndexKeys;
var keys = builder.Text(x => ((Dog)x).MyText).Text(x => ((Cat)x).MyText);
col.Indexes.CreateOne(keys);
```

But got `Unable to determine the serialization information for x => Convert(x).Message.`

Comment: How does your `Cat`, `Dog` and `Animal` classes look like? Please post bare minimum testable code.

Comment: @Saleem TBH, I'm not sure it adds anything useful to understanding the question, but let's say that `Animal` only has a `Guid` `Id` property, `Dog` has a `string` property `DogText` and `Cat` has a `string` property `CatText`.

Comment: It's not about understanding but testing also. Problem may be crystal clear to you but think about others who have no clue of your thought process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by using field definitions that specify the JSON property name as a string:

```
var dogFieldDef = new StringFieldDefinition<Animal>("dog_only_field");
var catFieldDef = new StringFieldDefinition<Animal>("cat_only_field");

var builder = Builders<Animal>.IndexKeys;

var key = builder
    .Text(dogFieldDef)
    .Text(catFieldDef);

col.Indexes.CreateOne(key);
```